# How to add disable cursor pointer in config tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

how to add setting in tailwind.config.js if screen size is less than 780px then disable all cursor-pointers?

note *I'm using nextjs and tailwind*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @ahmed is almost correct. In the docs there is no `cursor-disabled`

If you look at the docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/cursor) you can see that Tailwind offer a `cursor-none` property.

The best way to set this is like Ahmed said, in your `global.css` file you an do something like

```css
* {
   @apply cursor-none md:cursor-auto
}
```

Here you're using md: which is the breakpoint for `768px` `min-width`

But the question would be why would you want to disable the cursor on small screens? If it's mobile there wont be any cursor anyways?